# Configure FileBeat to combine all logs without multiline pattern

Tags: logstash, multiline, filebeat

I am using Filebeat 6.4.2, Logstash 6.3.1 and want to combine all logs files on the filebeat input path  . Logs don't have any specific pattern to start with or end with.

Logs don't have any specific pattern. I want to capture all combined logs to Logstash together in bunch of max lines specified.

I tried with multiple RegEx in the pattern sections, it's not working. Problem is logs does'nt come in any specific pattern.

```
filebeat.inputs:

    - type: log
      enabled: true
      paths:
        - /var/log/application.log
      fields:
        type: admin
        tags: admin
      fields_under_root: true

      multiline.pattern:  '.' 
      multiline.negate: true
      multiline.match: after
      multiline.max_lines: 1000

output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["xxx.20.x.xxx:5043"]
```

I want to combine all the multiline logs together as per max_lines configuration’s .

Comment: You didn't tell what is the result of this configuration, what is "not working" ?

Comment: The result of the above configuration is each logs comes as a separate document in logstash, but multiline configuration in filebeat is to combine logs together in a single event and send it to logstash.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a pattern that would **not be found** in your logs like

> '^HeLlO$€(^_^)€$bYe'

and it should do the trick.